# Synchronous/Blocking Application.Invoke() for GTK#

Tags: c#, .net, mono, multithreading, gtk#

Unfortunately, `Application.Invoke()` is asynchronous:

```
private string ThreadFunction(int i)
{
    string result = null;

    Gtk.Application.Invoke(delegate
    {
        OutputStringToUserInterface("i = " + i.ToString());
        result = GetStringFromUserInterface();
    });

    return result;
}
```

This means that in this example `ThreadFunction()` proceeds immediately after calling `Application.Invoke()`, resulting in an probably undefined state of the `result` string. -- Typically `ThreadFunction()` will be faster and will return with the old value (i.e. `null`).

This is a workaround using `ManualResetEvent` to make `Application.Invoke()` synchronous:

```
private string ThreadFunction(int i)
{
    string result = null;

    using (var ev = new ManualResetEvent(false))
    {
        Gtk.Application.Invoke(delegate
        {
            OutputStringToUserInterface("i = " + i.ToString());
            result = GetStringFromUserInterface();

            ev.Set();
        });

        ev.WaitOne();
    }

    return result;
}
```

This way, `ThreadFunction()` waits until `Application.Invoke()` returns, like it would do using [WinForms Control.Invoke()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx).

**EDIT:** Better example code

**EDIT2:** Add missing `using`

Now my question: **Is there a better solution?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, yes, there's no reason to wait for the delegate to execute to get the proper return value.  Fix:

```
int result = i + 1;
```

And it's okay to let the OutputStringToUserInterface() execute asynchronously, assuming you don't call ThreadFunction() so often that it floods the UI thread with requests.

If your real code actually depends on a return value from a function that must run on the UI thread then, no, you can't make it faster.  Clearly, that's something you *really* want to avoid.

Comment: OK +1. So you don't think there is a better alternative (concerning resource consumption) than the one suggested above?

Comment: Resource consumption?  A ManualResetEvent is very cheap.

Answer (score 2):

You can encapsulate your current code into a generic wrapper:

```
public static void GuiInvoke(Action action)
{
    var waitHandle = new ManualResetEventSlim();
    Gtk.Application.Invoke( (s,a) => 
                            {
                                action();
                                waitHandle.Set();
                            });
    waitHandle.Wait();
}

public static void BeginGuiInvoke(Action action)
{
    Gtk.Application.Invoke( (s,a) => {action();});
}
```